# Problem with notification bar in rooted droid

Tags: rooting, root-access, samsung

I just now rooted my Galaxy Pocket S-5300. Now when I rebooted,my notification bar is vanished! I could not Find it anywhere. Besides when I try to open "About Phone" In settings it force closes. Please help me fast!

Comment: What steps did you take to root it? Likely that's the source of the problem.

Comment: I followed the steps from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=rQYt19P_coE . Please help!

Comment: I would try reverting back to stock and redoing the rooting procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice, backup /data/ and sdcard (not external), use OTA ROOT KEEPER, do a factory reset, and restore data and the root. 
Instead of rk, try first Framaroot.

Comment: Ya,I unrooted it,will do the next step soon!